# I need an easy way to extract data from a few thousand emails (apple mail)

Tags: email, apple-mail

I have about 2000 emails from a web contest my company did. All the emails are arranged in the following fashion:

```
You have received a new contest submission.  Here are the details:
Name: Bob Jones 
Email: bobjones@internet.com 
Location: Springfield, MA 
Age: 83 
Mailinglist: true
```

All of these emails are saved in apple mail, is there any way I can extract this data into a text file, excel sheet, or something else more useable?

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up selecting all emails, left clicking, and selecting "forward". It compiles all the text from the emails into one massive email. Hard to work with, but certainly easier than a ton of separate emails.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might come way too late, but there are actually different solutions available out there which can do that. Have a look at:

- email2db.com
- mailparser.io
- getdispatch.com

Might be cheaper and easier to use one of them instead of developing this yourself. Especially if it is a one-time task you need to perform.